# Some questions about complex curves in $\mathbb CP^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, complex-geometry, projective-space

I would like to ask for some clarifications in the following questions about complex curves.

1. My first question is if I correctly understand what the complex curve in $\mathbb CP^2$ is.  Is it only a set which is locally given as the nullset of some analytic function with non-zero gradient at each zero? If this is correct, what is the complex curve with boundary?
2. If I understand the definition of complex curve correctly, then the complex curve needn't to be a Riemann surface in general, it may have finite number of points in which it fails to be a smooth manifold. With these points excluded it is a Riemann surface. Right?
3. I know the definition of the normalization of a complex curve (A holomorphic map from a Riemann surface to this complex curve such that ...), but in one article the authors used in this definition meromorphic map instead of holomorphic one. What is the meromorphic map in this context? Does one call by a meromorphic map from a Riemann surface to $\mathbb C^2$ a holomorphic map from this Riemann surface to $\mathbb CP^2$?

Answer (score 0):

1. no your understanding is a little bit off, while not being off. If we define a complex curve locally as the nullset of some analytic function with non-zero gradient by the implicit function theorem we will get that we can locally express one variable as analytic function of the other: $(z,w(z))$ on some open subset of the space. We can now define a complex atlas on our curve via the projection on the first variable, or saying that our curve is locally the graph on an analytic function and so it is a Riemann surface. To define a Riemann surface with boundary we use the same definition used for smooth manifolds: we ask for the atlas to contain homeomorphisms with the half-disk: $D_0^+=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,:\,|z|<1\, ,\, \Im(z)\geq 0\}$.
2. At this point here you understand what you get. Note that we can define Riemann surfaces in many ways and in such ways we may have to be careful at some points as you mentioned, but there are many ways to eliminate such problems such as plugging holes.
3. And here when we talk of meromorphic maps between Riemann Surfaces what we mean is the underlying map in the local coordinates to be meromorphic. You need to talk about meromorphic maps or functions every time you deal with compact surfaces because of the Riemann-Roch Theorem.

Hope it was clear enough!

Comment: Thank you, with Riemann surfaces it is clear, but what is the complex curve (and complex curve with boundary) then?

Comment: Your definition of complex curve give raise to a Riemann surface.

Comment: Yes, but what is the correct definition of a complex curve (maybe without boundary)? It is used in many articles without explanation.

Comment: A complex curve is a curve with a complex structure, i.e. a Riemann surface, there is no difference. As one define a real curve to be something with a differentiable structure, you define a complex curve to be something with a holomorphic structure. You may think of it as the set of zeroes of some homogeneous polynomial, the have an algebraic approach, but you will still obtain a Riemann surface, that is a complex curve.

Comment: I'm not sure it is the same thing. Any algebraic curve in $\mathbb CP^2$ is a complex curve and it may have singularities (e.g. self-intersections) and a curve with self-intersection can't be even a manifold

Comment: Yes you are right, I made a mistake. But in fact you can just eliminate those points and obtain a RS. If you want to have a closed RS you can "plug" those holes. When you speak about curve I think about the analytic definition and in some way or another go back to a RS. On the other hand you define an Algebraic curve, which may have singularities, but outside some finite set is a RS but is not one in general. In fact you may now about the correspondence of compact RS and nonsingular algebraic projective curves. So the algebraic curves are more.

Comment: P.S. as a locus of a polynomial it is not classical to look for a boundary because it is defined everywhere on $\mathbb{C}P^2$ But you can just take the closure of an open subset of it.

Comment: Look, here https://www.imj-prg.fr/~bernard.teissier/documents/trieste.pdf the author defines a complex curve locally as the image of a holomorphic map. Is it the correct definition of a complex curve? Maybe we should additionally require this map to be non-degenerate?

Comment: Yes, it is. If you ask it to be non degenerative you will again obtain a Riemann surface. But can I ask you why are you so obsessed about it?

Comment: Just to be sure about basics.

Comment: Try reading the first chapter of "Rick Miranda, Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces"

Comment: Thanks for the reference. By the way, about the third question. A meromorphic $\mathbb C$-valued function on a Riemann surface is the same as a holomorphic map to $\mathbb CP^1$. Is it true that also a meromorphic $\mathbb C^2$-valued function is the same as a holomorphic map to $\mathbb CP^2$? I faced with meromorphic $\mathbb C^2$-valued functions here https://www.imj-prg.fr/~guennadi.henkin/IDNpbReconstruction.pdf

Comment: A meromorphic $\mathbb{C}^2$-valued function I take to be a couple of meromorphic functions $(f(z),g(z))$ and so at some discrete set $D$ they will not be defined. As such they can be regarded as a holomorphic map to $\mathbb{C}P^1\times\mathbb{C}P^1$.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking like this at first. But in this article the situation is as follows: there is a Riemann surface with boundary, the boundary is embedded in $\mathbb C^2$. The embedded real curve is shown to bound some complex curve $Y$ in $\mathbb CP^2$. The embedding map is said to extend meromorphically to the whole Riemann surface and the extended map is said to be the usual normalization of $Y$. In this context it seems for me that meromorphic $\mathbb C^2$ valued is the same as holomorphic $\mathbb CP^2$ valued.

Comment: You have a function from a real curve to $\mathbb{C}^2$. You get that the image of the curve bounds some complex curve $Y$ in $\mathbb{C}P^2$, and you have that if the real curve bounded a RS then the function from the boundary to the curve extends to the whole RS meromorphically and this is the normalization of complex curve $Y$. So now you have a holomorphic map from the RS to $Y$. At no point you get to really deal with $\mathbb{C}P^2$, it is the same as having a complex curve in $\mathbb{C}P^2$ and normalizing it. It just tells you that the meromorphic map is just holomorphic but in $Y$.